# Connecting HDMI MediaCenter PC to Standard Def TV

Tags: hdmi, tv, htpc, media-center, nvidia-ion

I just purchased a ASRock ION 330-HT-BD to use as my new Media Center. Sadly I still have a crappy standard-def old tube TV for the foreseeable future.

The TV has Coax & Composite (Red, White, Yellow) inputs, and my new MediaCenterr has HDMI & VGA outputs.

So my question is, how do I hook up the two together!

All of the HDMI-to-Composite cables I have found explicitly state that they can not be used to hook a PC up to a TV.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, after quite a bit more searching, I found a solution:

[VideoSecu VGA2TV](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000X3FAJU)

[Sabrent TV-PC85](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002CMAW20)

Comes with the *to-be-expected* video quality issues, but I knew that going into this. And it's drastically cheaper then the other solutions. So until I get a sweet sweet HDTV, this is my hold over solution.

Comment: This is probably better than the HDMI solution anyway, as you don't have to worry about content protection issues.

Comment: @Adam - How did that work out for you? Which model did you get and would your recommend it? I'm looking to do the same thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it properly, but it's not cheap.

http://www.hdtvsupply.com/hdmi-to-composite.html

Note the BIG DISCLAIMER included on the page:

> Note: Since this HDMI / DVI to
>   Composite Video and S-Video Converter
>   is HDCP Compliant, a content protected
>   HDMI input will not result in a
>   picture. That means no DVD's, no
>   Blu-rays, no games and DVD's in a PS3,
>   etc.

You can thank the movie companies for this.  They want complete control over what you do with the signals from an HDTV-compliant device.